# Pivot table (extracting row-specific data) in R

Tags: r, reshape2, subset

I have monthly rainfall data for a location for a period of 150 yrs predicted by 22 different models. The columns look like:
Year Month Model1 Model2 Model3 .....Model 22

The data look like:

```
1950 1 75 90 120...67
1950 2 .. .. .. .. ..
1950 (repeat 12 times for 12 months of the year)
1951
...
2099
```

I am interested in extracting only the June through August data by model and then finding the sum for these 3 months. I've used the subset feature before and the melt feature (reshape package) but I'm not sure how to combine the two. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,
V

Answer (score 2):

This should get you there: Using `dplyr`. Using akrun's data

```
df %>%
  filter(Month %in% 6:8) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum),-Month)


  Year     Model1     Model2    Model3
1 1950  1.3107384 -0.3295989 -1.521790
2 1951 -3.7768090  1.0092107  1.737716
3 1952  0.5202926  2.6768969  1.890024
```

Comment: Would it be more compact to use `summarise_each(funs(sum), -Month)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Month %in% 6:8, lapply(.SD, sum), by=Year, .SDcols= -"Month"]
#   Year     Model1     Model2    Model3
#1: 1950  1.3107384 -0.3295989 -1.521790
#2: 1951 -3.7768090  1.0092107  1.737716
#3: 1952  0.5202926  2.6768969  1.890024
```

We obtain those row indices where `Month` is 6, 7 or 8, and on that subset, we compute mean of all columns except `Month` (specified in `.SDcols`) while grouping by `Year`.

Additionally, we can also `setkey` on the *data.table*, that speeds up the *subset* operation tremendously with the help of binary search - [see vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944).

```
setkey(setDT(df), Month) ## reorders `df` by `Month`
df[J(6:8), lapply(.SD, sum), by=Year, .SDcols= -"Month"]
```

Note that just the first part changed from `Month %in% 6:8` to `J(6:8)`. The latter performs a binary search based subset on the key column `Month`. Everything else is intact.

If you do repeated subsetting or work with *very large data sets*, keying data.tables and subsetting using binary search would improve performance tremendously. Refer to the vignettes for more info.

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(Year= rep(1950:1952,each=12), Month=rep(1:12,3), 
            Model1=rnorm(36), Model2=rnorm(36), Model3=rnorm(36))
```